can't boot back in windows after setting up dual boot
I'm new to linux, this is how i ended up in this: at first, grub menu didn't show up (it still don't) so I tried to add ubuntu to windows boot management section. ended up windows automaticly booting into linux. (yes, bios boot order is in: 1: windows 2:ubuntu). I really need help

UEFI installs or BIOS installs? No idea how to fix Windows issues, best to ask on a Windows forum. Boot-Repair is really only for Linux, perhaps some minor repairs for old BIOS installs of Windows. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

i broke windows thats why it was booting to linux automaticly. thank you for the help
